# Search failed by child type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an abstract class and its child.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@DiscriminatorValue(EntityEnum.Values.APPEALS)
public class Appeals extends EntityAbstract {
    public Appeals(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "text")
    @Column(name = "guid", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private String guid;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "content", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String content;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "changed_at", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime changedAt;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_parent")
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
//@MappedSuperclass
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)})
public abstract class EntityAbstract implements Content {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "guid")
    private String guid;

    @Version
    private Integer version;
}
```

I use Spring Data and try to make a request:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityAbstract, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<EntityAbstract> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EntityAbstract e WHERE TYPE(e) = :type AND e.guid = :guid")
    <E extends EntityAbstract> E findByGuidAndType(String guid, Class<E> type);
}
```

I make the call like this:

```
entityRepository.findByGuidAndType(guid, Appeals.class);
```

I get this error:
**org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [type] not set; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [type] not set**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the name `:type` is some kind of reserved keyword, as the `TYPE` operator may suggest. Try to rename it to something like `clazz`.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I tried with the name discriminator - the effect is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is a much more easy way to solve the problem. You are using a type class parameter `Class<E>` in the `findByGuidAndType(String guid, Class<E> type)` method whereas you shoudl use a `<? extends EntityAbstract>` type because in a first case Spring knows nothing about a `E` but if you will declare it as an inheritor of the `EntityAbstract` Spring will start match classes properly. So the repo interface will be like this:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityAbstract, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<EntityAbstract> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EntityAbstract e WHERE TYPE(e) = :type AND e.guid = :guid")
    <E extends EntityAbstract> E findByGuidAndType(String guid, Class<? extends EntityAbstract> type);
}
```

At least it works for me as expected

Comment: And what does your option look like, can you write in full? Something like this? This option does not compile
    `@Query("SELECT e FROM EntityAbstract e WHERE TYPE(e) = :type AND e.guid = :guid")
    <? extends EntityAbstract> ? findByGuidAndType(String guid, Class<?> type);`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ResponseDto findByGuid(String guid, Class<?> name) {
    Optional<EntityAbstract> guid1 = entityRepository.findOne(((Specification<EntityAbstract>)
            (root, query, builder) ->
                    findInField(guid, () -> root.get("guid"), builder, query))
            .and((root, query, builder) ->
                    builder.equal(root.type(), builder.literal(name))
            )
    );
    EntityAbstract entityAbstract = guid1.orElse(null);
    return representateToDto(entityAbstract);
}

private Predicate findInField(Object element,
                                    Supplier<Path<?>> pathSupplier,
                                    CriteriaBuilder builder,
                                    CriteriaQuery<?> query) {
    query.distinct(true);
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(element)
            ? builder.conjunction()
            : pathSupplier.get().in(element);
}
```